# How to insert into database when using JTA + JPA with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jta, atomikos

I have a simple web application using JTA + JPA along with Spring (version 4).
I am doing a XA transaction using Atomikos JTA transaction Manager. This transaction involves inserting EmployeeA entity into DatabaseA and another EmployeeB entity into another DatabaseB.

Strangely, the application does not throw any error **but no enteries are inserted into the Databases.**

```
public class JtaTest {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    JtaTest test = new JtaTest();
    test.testMandatory();
}

private static void testMandatory() {

    final SpringContextUtil util = SpringContextUtil.instance();
    ApplicationContext ctx = util.getApplicationContext();


    final JtaEmployeeService employeeService = (JtaEmployeeService)ctx.getBean("jtaEmployeeService");
    EmployeeA a = new EmployeeA();
    a.setName("emp-a-1");
    a.setAge(30);

    EmployeeB b = new EmployeeB();
    a.setName("emp-b-1");
    a.setAge(31);

   try {
    employeeService.persistEmployees(a, b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
   System.out.println("success");
}
}
```

---

**The service class implementation:**

```
@Service("jtaEmployeeService")
public class JtaEmployeeServiceImpl implements JtaEmployeeService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("employeea")
private GenericDao<Integer, EmployeeA> employeeADao;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("employeeb")
private GenericDao<Integer, EmployeeB> employeeBDao;

@Override

@Transactional( propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void persistEmployees(EmployeeA employeeA, EmployeeB employeeB)  throws Exception {
    employeeADao.save(employeeA);
    employeeBDao.save(employeeB);
    System.out.println("Saving employee A and employee B ");


}
}
```

**The DAO implementation and interfaces:**

---

```
@Repository("employeeb")
public class EmployeeBDaoImpl extends AbstractJTADaoDatabaseB implements
    GenericDao<Integer, EmployeeB> {

@Override
public void save(EmployeeB entity) {
    super.persist(entity);

}
}

@Repository("employeea")
public class EmployeeADaoImpl extends AbstractJTADaoDatabaseA implements
    GenericDao<Integer, EmployeeA> {

@Override
public void save(EmployeeA entity) {
    super.persist(entity);

}
}

public abstract class AbstractJTADaoDatabaseB {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnitB")
@Qualifier("myManager")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(Object entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);

    // entityManager.flush();
}

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

}

public abstract class AbstractJTADaoDatabaseA {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnitA")
@Qualifier("myManager")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(Object entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    // entityManager.flush();
}

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

}
```

**Servlet-Context.xml**

---

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
 
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />
 
 <!--  Enables annotaion driven transactional support on springs -->
 <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hTransactionManager"/> -->
 <!--  <tx:jta-transaction-manager transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"/> -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"/>

<!--  list the packages which are annotated with springs annotaions like @controller, @repository, @service, @component only -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.controller.business, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.controller.rest, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.service, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.dao" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </beans:bean>
   

 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</beans:bean>

<!--  <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
      <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</beans:prop>
       
       <!--  <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop> -->
         <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
          <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</beans:prop>
             <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</beans:prop>
              <beans:prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">${net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName}</beans:prop>
       
      </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
   
       <!--<beans:property name="annotatedClasses">  -->
  <!--  packagesToScan is meant to give the package where the javax.persistence.Entity classes are stored , recognised via their annotations-->
  <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
      <beans:list>
        <beans:value>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model</beans:value>
      </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    
  </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</beans:bean>

    
    <beans:bean id = "hTransactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>   
 
<!--  Jata transactions with Atomikos  -->
<beans:bean id="dataSourceA" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
 <beans:property name="uniqueResourceName"><beans:value>DataSourceA</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaDataSourceClassName"><beans:value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaProperties">
     <beans:props>
  <beans:prop key="databaseName">traningdb</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="serverName">localhost</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="port">3306</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="password">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traningdb</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
 </beans:property>
 <beans:property name="minPoolSize"><beans:value>1</beans:value></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
 
<beans:bean id="dataSourceB" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
 <beans:property name="uniqueResourceName"><beans:value>DataSourceB</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaDataSourceClassName"><beans:value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaProperties">
     <beans:props>
  <beans:prop key="databaseName">traningdb2</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="serverName">localhost</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="port">3306</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="password">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traningdb2</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
 </beans:property>
 <beans:property name="minPoolSize">
 <beans:value>1</beans:value>
 </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactoryA" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitA" />
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceA" />
  <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactoryB" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitB" />
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceB" />
  <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"  init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
  <!--  <beans:property name="startupTransactionService" value="false" /> -->
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
  <beans:property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
  depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
  <beans:qualifier value="myManager"/>
  <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
  <beans:property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
  <beans:property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
 </beans:bean>

 
</beans:beans>
```

---

**Persistence.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitA" >
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeA</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>


  <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitB" >
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeB</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>

   <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
</persistence>
```

Any help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of head-whacking and many hit-and-trial debugging, finally able to solve the problem.
Looks like below property is required in the persistence.xml

> **hibernate.transaction.jta.platform**

On a application server there are multiple options available as [Different JTA paltform services](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#services-JtaPlatform)

But since I needed one standalone JTA platform implementation so I added one of my own.

> com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform

So here is my modified persistence.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitA" transaction-type="JTA" >
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeA</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>

<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"       value="com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform" />
  <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitB" transaction-type="JTA">
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeB</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"       value="com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform" />
   <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
</persistence>
```

**The source code for com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform**

```html
package com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform;

import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform;

import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;

public final class AtomikosJtaPlatform extends AbstractJtaPlatform {

        private TransactionManager utm = new UserTransactionManager();
        
        private UserTransaction userTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();
        
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -74991083213512919L;

        @Override
        protected TransactionManager locateTransactionManager() {
                return utm;
        }

        @Override
        protected UserTransaction locateUserTransaction() {
                return userTransaction;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some additional tuning:
1. Removing all hibernate ( jpa properties ) from persistence.xml to the servlet-context.xml.

Added **jpaProperties** to **EntityManagerFactoryA** and **EntityManagerFactoryB**

---

**Servlet-context.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
 
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />
 
 <!--  Enables annotaion driven transactional support on springs -->
 <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hTransactionManager"/> -->
 <!--  <tx:jta-transaction-manager transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"/> -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"/>

<!--  list the packages which are annotated with springs annotaions like @controller, @repository, @service, @component only -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.controller.business, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.controller.rest, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.service, com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.dao" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </beans:bean>
   

 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</beans:bean>

<!--  <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
      <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</beans:prop>
       
       <!--  <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop> -->
         <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
          <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</beans:prop>
             <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</beans:prop>
              <beans:prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">${net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName}</beans:prop>
       
      </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
   
       <!--<beans:property name="annotatedClasses">  -->
  <!--  packagesToScan is meant to give the package where the javax.persistence.Entity classes are stored , recognised via their annotations-->
  <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
      <beans:list>
        <beans:value>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model</beans:value>
      </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    
  </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</beans:bean>

    
    <beans:bean id = "hTransactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>   
 
<!--  Jata transactions with Atomikos  -->
<beans:bean id="dataSourceA" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
 <beans:property name="uniqueResourceName"><beans:value>DataSourceA</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaDataSourceClassName"><beans:value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaProperties">
     <beans:props>
  <beans:prop key="databaseName">traningdb</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="serverName">localhost</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="port">3306</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="password">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traningdb</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
 </beans:property>
 <beans:property name="minPoolSize"><beans:value>1</beans:value></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
 
<beans:bean id="dataSourceB" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
 <beans:property name="uniqueResourceName"><beans:value>DataSourceB</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaDataSourceClassName"><beans:value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</beans:value></beans:property>
 <beans:property name="xaProperties">
     <beans:props>
  <beans:prop key="databaseName">traningdb2</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="serverName">localhost</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="port">3306</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="password">root</beans:prop>
  <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/traningdb2</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
 </beans:property>
 <beans:property name="minPoolSize">
 <beans:value>1</beans:value>
 </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactoryA" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitA" />
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceA" />
  <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
  
  <beans:property name="jpaProperties">  
           <beans:map>  
               <beans:entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value-ref="atomikosJtaPlatform" />
                
               <beans:entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            </beans:map>
          </beans:property>
          
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactoryB" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitB" />
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceB" />
  <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />    
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
  
  <beans:property name="jpaProperties">  
           <beans:map>  
               <beans:entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value-ref="atomikosJtaPlatform" />
               
               <beans:entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            </beans:map>
          </beans:property>
               
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="atomikosJtaPlatform" class="com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform">
      <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
      <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
   </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"  init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
  <!--  <beans:property name="startupTransactionService" value="false" /> -->
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
  <beans:property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
  depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
  <beans:qualifier value="myManager"/>
  <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
  <beans:property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
  <beans:property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
 </beans:bean>

 
</beans:beans>
```

---

**Persistence.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitA" transaction-type="JTA" >
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeA</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>

<!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"       value="com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform" /> -->
  

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitB" transaction-type="JTA">
  <class>com.goraksh.spring.tutorial.model.EmployeeB</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes />
  <properties>
<!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"       value="com.goraksh.spring.atomikos.jta.platform.AtomikosJtaPlatform" /> -->
   

  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
  
</persistence>
```